# how to use javascript and css in WebPart?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I am using publishing portal template. I am developing using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + ASP.Net. And I want to develop a WebPart, which refers css and javascript (.js) files. My question is (1) how to deploy css/javascript files and (2) how to write reference path (e.g. ../../themes from my code below) from webpart to refer to related css/javascript files?

BTW: the existing code of css/javascript/Webpart is from existing aspx code and I am migrating aspx code to a Webpart. The code works in aspx.

Currently my code looks like this,

```
<link type="text/css" href="../../themes/test.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../test.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use my HtmlHelper class.

```
class HtmlHelper
{
    public static void IncludeScript(Page page, String key, String location)
    {
        if (!page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered(key))
             page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(key, location);
    }

    public static void IncludeCSS(Page page, String src)
    {
        HtmlLink css = new HtmlLink();
        css.Href = src;
        css.Attributes["rel"] = "stylesheet";
        css.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
        css.Attributes["media"] = "all";

        page.Header.Controls.Add(css);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For javascript, there is [ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx145dw2.aspx)

There is not an equivalent method for css, but you can:

1. provide a list of class names, and suggest a css file, but not include one yourself
2. use [embedded resources](http://aspalliance.com/726)
3. add controls to the header:

(As I did here):

```
HtmlLink link = new HtmlLink();
link.Href = "Cases/EditStyles.css";
link.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
link.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(link);
```

Best practice says you should not include the css as I did above (or in embedded resources).  You should use method number 1 above.

Comment: Why I need to use client script manager to register it in order to use it in WebPart? Why I can not just reference css/javascript file from some relative path, just like what we did in html/aspx code?

Comment: Technically, you can. It will work (the path must relative to the page).  But what if you use the web part in multiple pages and the path is different?